# How To Deploy maven spring project from eclipse to apache tomcat server (live)

Tags: spring, apache, maven, tomcat

I have developed an web application using maven spring html css js bootstrap jsp servlet and all. While developing I was using Tomcat to deploy it in order to test it.

right now my devlopment is in progress and i want test it on local server,but as I am new to all this I dont know how to deploy my java web application on local server

nd i want to do something like "when i commit in code and run it then its effect on my web UI which put in server"

So please help me if you know to answer?

Comment: is your .war file created? do you need to run web app in a tomcat server in your machine?  are you familiar of how to start and stop tomcat?

Comment: but i want to do -->"When i commit the code its effect show on UI"

Comment: You will need to create a Jenkins job and add github plugin to this job. After adding github plugin you have to configure in both side(jenkins and github) to trigger automatic build on code push.

Comment: here is the link: https://learning-continuous-deployment.github.io/jenkins/github/2015/04/17/github-jenkins/